# How to make auto layout resize labels and other objects based on screen size

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, ios-autolayout

What constraints would make this view resize the labels 1-9 with a smaller font and label size in order to keep labels 1-9 within the view. I have tried using minimum font scale and pinning the labels to all sides of the view. Any tips and or help with auto layout and building responsive UI's in Xcode are appreciated thank you.

[image: iPhone 7 Plus]

iPhone 7 Plus screen size simulation

[image: iPhone 4s]

iPhone 4s screen size simulation

Comment: use scroll view for label scolling

Comment: @SpartanEngr1297 put them in scroll view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy!

You can use constraints like this:

[image]

After adding all constraints you need check UILabel configuration:

[image]

If you have question - you can ask :)

Comment: Do you know how you would maintain this same behavior of resizing the objects on the storyboard if the labels/images/buttons/etc. were not all the same size?

Answer (score 0):

I think [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSimpleConstraints.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH12-SW1), you can find answer to your question (Part: Two Equal-Width Views).
A idea lies inside of using additional view between the labels and strengthening first and last labels to a top  and a bottom edge of a parent view.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add some `NSLayoutConstraints` and change some `UILabel` Properties in the `UIStoryBoard` **Interface Editor** .. I have added an image and a gif for reference.[image: I have marked the properties here]

This gif image will give a detailed explanation :
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]